# Post_save received twice for one save even when using dispatch_uid

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals

I have my models in individual files:

```
models
\ 
 |__init__.py
 |event.py
 |a_thing.py
 |...
```

In `__init__.py` I import each model and after that I set the signal handling.

For the `Event` model I need some `post_save` handling.

This is the truncated version of `__init__.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from core.models.event import Event

# Event
@receiver(post_save, sender = Event)
def event_post_save(sender, dispatch_uid = 'nope', **kwargs):
    print kwargs.get('created')
    print '------'
```

Whenever I save an `Event` via the console the message in the `post_save` is printed once but whenever I use the admin interface it gets printed twice. This may be because I import the models inside `admin.py` as well.

Is there a workaround for this so that I can save Event objects from the admin interface without the `post_save` firing twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it my moving the signal handling to the views' `__init__.py` instead of models' `__init__.py`

Answer (score 4):

It's probably from Django/Python import silliness.  You need [`dispatch_uid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) like you have, but I think it needs to be an argument to the decorator, not the handler itself.